# Generate filename for a copied file

Tags: java, file, io

I am looking to get similar behaviour to what you get in Windows when you copy and paste a file in the same directory.

For e.g, if you've copy/paste a file called `foo.txt`, it will create `foo Copy.txt` and if you paste it once more, it creates `foo Copy(2).txt` and if you copy/paste `foo Copy.txt`, `foo Copy Copy.txt` is created.

Is there a Java utility function that does this? I've looked at `File.createTempFile` but the filename it generates is too long and contains a UID-like substring.

Comment: I am not aware of any API, but it would be simple enought to write it yourself 'if(file.exists)' ...

Answer (score 0):

By using the FileChooser in combination with the "showSaveDialog"-method you will get the result you want, because java is then using the OS behaviour for existing files.

Comment: I don't want the user to have to enter anything in a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you just have to do the work first, it will give you an appreciation for the API.  Then you can write your own utility methods

```
File original = new File("build.xml");
String path = original.getAbsoluteFile().getParent();
String name = original.getName();
String ext = name.substring(name.indexOf("."));
name = name.substring(0, name.indexOf("."));
name = path + File.separator + name;

int index = 1;
File copy = new File(name + " (" + index + ")" + ext);
while (copy.exists()) {
    index++;
    copy = new File(name + " (" + index + ")" + ext);
}
System.out.println(copy);
```

Comment: So is that a no? In any case, <sarcasm>thanks for showing how a loop works.</sarcasm>

Comment: Yes, that would be a *No*, but SO wouldn't let me put that into an answer ;)